# Can a custom sklearn model be uploaded to gcloud ml-engine?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I have tried out the new functionality to deploy an sklearn model to ml-engine following the [gcloud tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/getting-predictions). I have created a wrapper for the sklearn Estimator GaussianMixture in order to alter the predict function so that it outputs probabilistic outputs (like sample_scores) instead of the default class predictions.

GMMWrapper.py

```
class GMMWrapper(GaussianMixture):
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.score_samples(X)
```

I create the pipeline and save it in a standard way:

```
gmm = GMMWrapper()
pipegmm = Pipeline([('gmm', gmm)])
pipegmm.fit(data)
with tf.gfile.Open(model_output_path, 'wb') as model_file:
    joblib.dump(pipegmm, model_output_path + '.joblib')
```

However when deploying to gcloud using `gcloud beta ml-engine versions create` of course it cannot find the module GMMWrapper

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with
error:  "Failed to load model: Could not load the model: 
/tmp/model/0001/model.joblib. No module named 'GMMWrapper'.
```

I have tried to include it in the deployment source folder which will be uploaded to the staging bucket.

```
DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE="/folder-containing-model-and-GMMWrapper"
MODEL_NAME="GMMs"
FRAMEWORK="SCIKIT_LEARN"
STAGING_BUCKET="gs://sklearn-models"

gcloud beta ml-engine versions create v1 \
    --model $MODEL_NAME --origin $DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE \
    --framework $FRAMEWORK --staging-bucket $STAGING_BUCKET \
    --runtime-version=1.5 --python-version=3.5
```

But that returns the same error. I would need to somehow inform gcloud where to look for the module. I suspect this cannot be done, but thought I would ask in case there is a way.

(Alternatively, if theres a way to change which function is called when calling predict on the pipeline that could also solve my problem.)

Comment: We're currently looking to support your use case. We'd love it if you can reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com so we can better understand your use case.

Comment: Sure, anything specific I should put in the subject line so you can find it?

Comment: Nope. We monitor all such emails :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not currently supported. We're always seeking ways to improve the product and will take this suggested feature into account.

Comment: Hi @rhaertel80, is there any update about this feature request?

Comment: This should be available as a limited preview in a couple of weeks. Please email cloudml-feedback@google.com if you are interested in joining.